# FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, error> (Rejecting invalid message: quickfix.IncorrectTagValue: Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag, field=528 field=528

Tags: quickfix

**We get the 528 tag error,**
FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, error> (Rejecting invalid message: quickfix.IncorrectTagValue: Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag, field=528 field=528:
FIXT.1.1:135->PSE, error> (Reject sent for Message 183: Value is incorrect (out of range) for this tag, field=528:528)

this is my configuration quickFix- BeginString=FIXT.1.1 DefaultApplVerID=9 StartTime=09:00:00 Asia/Manila EndTime=16:30:01 Asia/Manila HeartBtInt=30 ReconnectInterval=30 ResetOnLogon=Y ResetOnLogout=Y ResetOnDisconnect=Y CheckLatency=N MaxLatency=120**

when i'm getting incoming request from PSE, got the 528=L which is not exist in QuickFix class- public static final int FIELD = 528;public static final char AGENCY = 'A';public static final char PROPRIETARY = 'G';public static final char INDIVIDUAL = 'I';public static final char PRINCIPAL = 'P';public static final char RISKLESS_PRINCIPAL = 'R';public static final char AGENT_FOR_OTHER_MEMBER = 'W';

only these are the fields used in QuickFix class how can handle "L" Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: I know you're new here, but your question is kind of a mess.  If the answer wasn't so obvious, I would have ignored your question entirely.  Please rewrite your question title and add some formatting to clear up your question.

Comment: no i'm not using xml file, using java's interfaces and OrderCapacity is .class file of quickFix which exist only some values of 528 tag now i've to add more values in this class.
below is my .class file but in that class "L" is not exist.

Comment: package quickfix.field;

import quickfix.CharField;


public class OrderCapacity extends CharField {

 static final long serialVersionUID = 20050617;

 public static final int FIELD = 528;
 public static final char AGENCY = 'A';
 public static final char PROPRIETARY = 'G';
 public static final char INDIVIDUAL = 'I';
 public static final char PRINCIPAL = 'P';
 public static final char RISKLESS_PRINCIPAL = 'R';
 public static final char AGENT_FOR_OTHER_MEMBER = 'W';
 
 public OrderCapacity() {
  super(528);
 }

 public OrderCapacity(char data) {
  super(528, data);
 }

Comment: Strange, you are the second or third user in the last weeks where I recall that they did not use a dictionary and were having problems with the same field. If you want to add values to the message classes then you either need to override them or rebuild QFJ to have the values added to the classes.

Comment: How i can override the class?

Comment: 1) Always use an xml dictionary.  Always always always.  2) that comment where you pasted a bunch of code is useless.  Please learn how to format your post, and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your counterparty has added some custom values to the 528 enum.

You need to customize your DataDictionary xml file to match your counterparty's expectations.  Ask them if they have an xml file they can give you, or else you'll need to use their interface spec as a guide and create your own.